# How do I set an encoding type on NSInputStream?

Tags: ios, nsurlrequest, foundation, nsinputstream, windows-1252

I need to stream an image to a .NET backend service using Windows 1252 encoding. So I believe I need to create a `NSURLRequest` with its `HTTPBodyStream` set to a `NSInputStream` which is created with image data. And I need the encoding to be set to Windows 1252 or `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding`.

I really have two questions:

1. How do I tell `NSInputStream` to use `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` for its passed in data or file.
2. How would I convert a UIImage to ``NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` data? I only know of the base64 methods.

**Edit:**

This is the example .NET code that mimics a working client.

```
            wr.Method = "POST";
            wr.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            wr.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            string ImagePath = @"C:\Users\smith\Desktop\Cat-and-dog.jpg";

            byte[] ibuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(ImagePath);

            wr.ContentLength = ibuffer.Length;
            Stream pData = wr.GetRequestStream();
            pData.Write(ibuffer, 0, ibuffer.Length);
            pData.Close();

            HttpWebResponse wres = wr.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

            StreamReader strRdr = new StreamReader(wres.GetResponseStream(), enc);
            string resp = strRdr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't tell `NSInputStream` what encoding to use, because `NSInputStream` doesn't operate on strings. `NSInputStream` gives you raw bytes. It's your responsibility to decode those bytes using whatever input format you want.

   Also, since you “need to stream an image to a .NET backend service”, I think you want an `NSOutputStream`, not an `NSInputStream`. But it's the same deal: you give raw bytes to the output stream. You must encode your strings to bytes yourself.
2. The idea of converting a `UIImage` to any character encoding is somewhat nonsensical, because a `UIImage` is pixel data, not text. You first have to decode how you want to encode the pixel data. Let's say you want to encode it using PNG:

   ```
   UIImage *image = ...
   NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
   NSData *imageBase64Data = [imageData base64EncodedDataWithOptions:0];
   ```

   At this point, `imageBase64Data` contains the image, encoded as PNG, encoded as base 64, encoded as UTF-8. You might think that's the wrong character encoding, but base 64 encoding only uses printable ASCII characters. Since both CP1252 and UTF-8 are supersets of ASCII, the contents of `imageBase64Data` is also valid CP1252.

   If you'd rather have a string to explicitly encode, you can do this instead:

   ```
   NSString *imageBase64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions::0];
   NSData *imageBase64Data = [imageBase64String dataUsingEncoding: NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I agree it doesn't make sense to me but it is the spec. I have posted an the .NET client that works as an example.

Comment: I don't know .NET but it looks to me like your example code writes the raw JPEG data to the socket with no encoding whatsoever.